# How to implement a feature into two unrelated classes

Tags: java, oop

I was assigned to a project, and it is my job to implement a feature to the already existing system. This functionality needs to be added to two seperate classes. Both of these classes extend the same super class, but it does not make sense to add the feature to this superclass. What is the best way I can implement the same functionality into these two seperate classes without too much code duplication. The simple way would be implementing this functionality into a static class and then using the static methods in the two classes that need this extra functionality, but that sort of seems like bad design.

Is there any sort of design I can use to implement something like this, or is me running into this problem just showing a larger issue in the hierarchy that should be fixed rather than try to work on top of it?

Answer (score 2):

Java does not have stand-alone "static" classes, so that's a non-starter since it's not even possible. As for use of static methods, that's fine if you're talking about stateless utility methods.

Myself, I guess I'd solve this with composition and interfaces:

- Create an interface for the functionality that I desire
- Create concrete instance(s) of this interface
- Give the two classes fields of the interface
- Plus getter and setter methods for the interface.
- If the classes had to have the new behaviors themselves, then have them implement the interface, and then have these classes obtain the behaviors by "indirection" by calling the methods of the contained object in the interface methods.

---

I'm sorry that this answer is somewhat vague and overly general. If you need more specific advice from me or from anyone else here, then consider telling us more of the specifics of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Determine what common features of these two classes the new functionality relies on. Then, extract those features to an interface, modify the two classes to implement that interface, and put the new functionality code in its own class (or possibly a static method somewhere, e.g. `NewFeature.doTheThing(NewFeaturable toWhat)`) and make it operate on those interfaces.

If the existing classes have to obtain information from / call methods related to the "new feature", then give them a `NewFeature` field that is an instance of the new feature class and have them interact with that object. Pseudo-ish code:

```
interface NewFeaturable {
    int getRelevantInfo ();
}

class NewFeature {
    final NewFeaturable object;
    NewFeature (NewFeaturable object) { this.object = object; }
    void doSomething () { int x = object.getRelevantInfo(); ... }
}

class ExistingClass extends Base implements NewFeaturable {
    final NewFeature feature;
    ExistingClass () { ...; feature = new NewFeature(this); }
    @Override int getRelevantInfo () { ... }
    void doSomethingNew () { feature.doSomething(); }
}
```

Be wary of `new NewFeature(this)` there, as subclasses of `ExistingClass` will not be fully constructed when it is called. If it's an issue, consider deferring initialization of `feature` until it is needed.

A lot of the specifics depend on your exact situation, but hopefully you get the general idea.

Comment: Yep, composition and interfaces. 1+